# jQuery draggable doesn't apply containment on creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jQuery draggable plugin and faced with the next problem. After draggable creation, plugin doesn't apply specified containment option.

Here you can find an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qQYsj/.

```
// Containment will be applied after first move attempt
$('.item').draggable({ containment: [100, 100, 200, 200] });
```

Is there a way to apply containment without extra logic, that will calculate allowed position and place element to it? (this logic already exist in the plugin)

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any possible solution without adding duplicate logic (positioning algorithm already exist in draggable plugin, but i can't force plugin to execute it).

So i added next code to update item position:

```
function updateItemPosition(item, container)
{
    var itemRect = getRect(item), currentPosition = item.position(),
        position = getItemPosition(getRect(container), itemRect);

    item.css('top', position.top - itemRect.top + currentPosition.top + 'px')
        .css('left', position.left - itemRect.left + currentPosition.left + 'px');
}

function getRect(target)
{
    var result = target.offset();

    result.width = target.outerWidth();
    result.height = target.outerHeight();

    return result;
}

function getItemPosition(containerRect, itemRect)
{
    var result = {};

    result.top = Math.max(containerRect.top, Math.min(containerRect.top + containerRect.height - itemRect.height, itemRect.top));
    result.left = Math.max(containerRect.left, Math.min(containerRect.left + containerRect.width - itemRect.width, itemRect.left));

    return result;
}
```

And it should be used like:

```
updateItemPosition($('.item'), $('.placeholder'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but this might be an option...

```
.item
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
}


// Containment will be applied after first move attempt
var xpos = 100,
    ypos = 100;
$('.item').css({
    "top": ypos+"px",
    "left": xpos+"px"
  }).draggable({ containment: [ypos, xpos, 200, 200] });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qQYsj/1/

Comment: I need a way to simulate dragging attempt and plugin will apply specified containment. Thx.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "simulate dragging attempt".

Comment: I realy hope, that there is a way to force draggable to apply containment. By "simulate dragging attempt" i mean something like $('.item').trigger('drag');

Answer (score 0):

I think that your draggable containment is working as its intended to. Your draggable element isn't within that container though.

Why not just use CSS to place your `.item` inside the containment area to begin with?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/qQYsj/2/)**

```
.item
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left:100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

On second thought, when you say "simulate dragging" are you talking about something like this:

**[jsfiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/qQYsj/3/)**

```
// drag will start after dragging 100px
$('.item').draggable({ 
    containment: [100, 100, 200, 200],
    distance: 100
});
```

Comment: In fact i dont have access to allowed position. I mean that i have only selector (something like '.placeholder', and yes i can calculate cotainment using jquery and specify it as containment for .item). Variant with CSS doesn't solve my problem, each time placeholder changes its position. So i need a way to force draggable to apply containment (like move attempt but programmatically). Child is located outside of placeholder.